# Can I update multiple columns at once with multiple conditionals?

Tags: mysql-5.7, update

Having the following table snippet:

```
CREATE TABLE `some_table` (
    `exp_col_1` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `mark_col_1_as_exported` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0',
    `exp_col_2` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0',
    `mark_col_2_as_exported` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0',
);
```

is there a way to write one query for:

- update the column `mark_col_1_as_exported` where `exp_col_1=1`
- update the column `mark_col_2_as_exported` where `exp_col_2=1`

I know I can write an UPDATE for each of them but this is just a snippet, we are talking here about 20 cols to be updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using case would be an option :

```
UPDATE some_table
  SET mark_col_1_as_exported = CASE WHEN exp_col_1 = 1 THEN 0 ELSE mark_col_1_as_exported END , 
      mark_col_2_as_exported = CASE WHEN exp_col_2 = 2 THEN 0 ELSE mark_col_2_as_exported END 
  WHERE exp_col_1=1 OR exp_col_2=2;
```

It might have some performance issues because of the usage of `or` operator.

*Note*. Please  use it on an testig environment first

See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/vs3Yna8i)